# Using JSoup to select a group of tags

Tags: java, jsoup

I am attempting to use JSoup to scrape some information off a page, which can be identified by a group of tags in a particular order. The order of them is as follows:

```
 <span class="sold" >Sold</span></td>
    <td class='prc'>
        <div  class="g-b bidsold" itemprop="price">
                AU $1.00</div>
```

I am looking to grab each value that is in place of the AU $1.00 field on the page, but they can only be identified by the `span class="sold"` selector that occurs a few tags beforehand.

I have tried something like `select("span.sold:lt(4) + [itemprop=price]")` but feel like I'm flailing around in the dark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should do the trick!!!

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(/*URL of your HTML document*/").get();
Element part = doc.body();
Elements parts = part.getElementsByTag("div");
String attValue;
String requiredContent;
for(Element ent : parts)
{
    if(ent.hasAttr("class"))
    {
        attValue = ent.attr("class");
        if(attValue.equals("g-b bidsold"))
        {
            System.out.println("\n");
            requiredContent=ent.text();
            System.out.println(requiredContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Just make sure to iterate and get the output in an array.

Comment: Thanks - that works just as expected! I can see that it pulls all the div tags out as elements, then checks if they have a class that equals g-b bidsold, but how is it selecting the previous part (i.e. class=sold)? Just trying to wrap my head around the code so I can repeat it elsewhere if necessary!

Comment: You're welcome! The code I've given is not checking the previous part. It just looks for the content inside div with the specific class. If you need to check the class of span tag too, you need to rewrite this code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this:

`Elements soldPrices = doc.select("td:has(.sold) + td [itemprop=price]");`

That will return elements (the DIVs) that have price itemprops, which have immediately preceeding TDs with elements (the SPANs) with class=sold.

See the [Selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) for more details.